# How to start an animation each time when the function is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I have the following function which is called every time after a video is ended. But the animation is working only first time when the function is called. There is any way to start every time when the function is called? I want to say that the console log message is showing every time.

```
function startResolveExp(){

    console.log('full panel video has ended');

    $('#resolve_exp_bg').fadeIn(3000);
    $('#resolve_exp_tt').fadeIn(3000);
    $('#resolve_exp_date').fadeIn(3000);
    $('#resolve_black_box').fadeOut(2500);
    $('#thumb_01').fadeIn(5000).animate({"top":"0px"},1500);
    $('#thumb_02').fadeIn(5000).animate({"top":"0px"},2000);
    $('#thumb_03').fadeIn(5000).animate({"top":"0px"},2500);

    TweenMax.to(exp_video_hldr, 0.4, { opacity:0, ease:Power1.easeInOut, onComplete:function () {exp_video_hldr.style.display = "none"} });
    resolve_exp.style.display = "block";
    TweenMax.to(resolve_exp, 0.2, { opacity:1, delay:0, ease:Power1.easeInOut});

    if(isFullscreen){
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen(); // Firefox
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen(); // IE
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
    }};

}
```

Comment: If you dont fade things out how should they fade in again?

Comment: can you create a fiddle with the html too?

Comment: @MarkusHayner: something I noticed, you seem to be using a mix of jQuery `animate()` as well as `TweenMax` for your animations. I should recommend that since you already have `TweenMax` loaded, do all your animations using it and avoid jQuery's `animate` (or `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`) calls completely. If you can create a fiddle, I would be happy to help you out with that.

Comment: @MarkusHayner: Tahir Ahmed is right,  you should use either jQuery or GSAP. Otherwise you will have both competing to set properties on your element, which results in conflicts. Best to just use GSAP since you get better performance than using jQuery `animate()` which uses `setInterval()` instead of RAF `requestAnimationFrame` which is in sync with the browser :)

Comment: correction jQuery uses `setTimeout` :)